# for /r returns non-existent files

Tags: for-loop, cmd

`for /r %i (<filename>) do` returns files that do not exist. E.g. in the detailed example below, the file `C:\Temp\2018-01\no\b.txt` ***does not exist***. Yet the `for` command returns that file as if it does. This causes problems when trying to perform some action for each `<filename>` in a directory tree.

How do I prevent the `for` command from returning non-existent files?

---

When using `for /r` to perform some action on all instances of a particular file within a directory tree, the loop returns the file even for directories that don't contain it. For example, the following command:

```
for /r %i in (<filename>) do @echo %i
```

outputs: `<path>\<filename>` for each directory in the tree, regardless of whether the file exists.

The following console session demonstrates.

```
C:\Temp\2018-01>copy con b.txt
 ^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Temp\2018-01>mkdir no\yes

C:\Temp\2018-01>copy b.txt no\yes
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Temp\2018-01>dir /a/s/b b.txt
C:\Temp\2018-01\b.txt
C:\Temp\2018-01\no\yes\b.txt

C:\Temp\2018-01>for /r %i in (b.txt) do @echo %i
C:\Temp\2018-01\b.txt
C:\Temp\2018-01\no\b.txt
C:\Temp\2018-01\no\yes\b.txt

C:\Temp\2018-01>
```

Notice above that the `dir` command lists the only 2 instances of `b.txt` whereas the `for` command also outputs a non-existent `...\no\b.txt`.

For the record, I've observed this on Windows 10, and Windows Server 2008 R2.  But I doubt the version really matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have a couple of workarounds for the above. But hopefully someone has an explanation for the problem, and possibly a better alternative.

The first option is to explicitly check that the file exists before performing the command. It's a little verbose, but should be reliable.

```
for /r %i in (b.txt) do @if exist "%i" echo %i
```

The second option is to use a wildcard forcing a search for all files matching the pattern. Theoretically this means it could match more files than intended. But careful placement of the wildcard can mitigate this.

```
for /r %i in (b.txt*) do @echo %i
```